# Plotly: always show hovertext

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Is there a parameter in Plotly (python) to make the hovertext boxes always show (i.e. rather than only when hovered over)?

The alternative is to make multiple annotations but I was hoping there might be a quicker solution.

Comment: [docs](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/)

Answer (score 1):

For a scatterplot I would create the 'text' attribute to the trace, then specify 'markers+lines+text' and a 'textposition'. This will plot some text next to every point that you specify. In the example below I've demonstrated that you can still use the `<br>` and `<b>` tags to style these labels. Obviously, depending on your data, you may need to position them a little more carefully.

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
trace = {'type' : 'scatter', 'x' : [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'y' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
'text' : ['a<br>aaa','<b>b</b>','c','d','e','f'], 'mode' : 'markers+text', 
'textposition' : 'center right'}
plotly.offline.iplot([trace])
```

For a barplot or other, this will be a lot more difficult. You will probably have to go the annotation route, although you may get some mileage out of the PostMessage API, specifically the [hover](https://github.com/plotly/postMessage-API#hover) task (Plotly tutorial [here](https://plot.ly/python/hover-events/)).

Hope this helps!